# How to share folder to multiple users using java code?

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to share the folder programatically in java. I want to share the folder to multiple users.
I  use the following command:

```
net share sharefolder=<drive path> /GRANT:<username>,FULL
```

the above command share the given drive path folder with the username with FULL acess i.e read and Write.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: It's not about java, you need to look how to use net share command. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490712.aspx

Comment: Actually i explore net share command but i didn't get what i want.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i have tried with net share command to share the folder with user. Also tried it multiple times but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple users you may use following command in your java code

```
net share sharefolder=<drivepath> /GRANT:<username>,Full /GRANT:<username>,Full
```

You can add as many users you need.
Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Use java process to run your command:

```
String yourCommand = "net share sharefolder=<drive path> /GRANT:<username>,FULL";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(yourCommand );

// To get the output of command            
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```

Comment: Thanks.
But that will grant permission to one user only not to multiple users.

Comment: @Kunal you can run same command multiple time for different user or, see  help of `net`  command if there is any way to give permission to multiple user at once then use same solution here also.

Comment: I tried that also but for 2nd time its prompting that folder is already share though username is different.